# Practice Java - EDX

Tags: java, arrays, object

Is the below implementation correct?

Input : Oldrecords (an Array of GameRecord Objects) and newRecords (GameRecord)

I will check for newRecord values in the oldRecords array. If its not present and the length of oldrecord array is less than 10, i will add newRecord to the updated array.

I am getting array bound of exception when the new record is added.

```
    if (size < 10){
            int length = size + 1;
            updatedRecords = new GameRecord[length];
            System.arraycopy(oldRecords, 0, updatedRecords, 0, size);
            updatedRecords[length]=newGameRecord(newRecord.getName(),newRecord.getLevel(),newRecord.getScore());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put it at `size`, not `length`.

```
if (size < 10){
  int length = size + 1;
  updatedRecords = new GameRecord[length];
  System.arraycopy(oldRecords, 0, updatedRecords, 0, size);
  updatedRecords[size]=newGameRecord(newRecord.getName(),newRecord.getLevel(),newRecord.getScore());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The possibility I see is the at the oldRecords array size would be less than the value of 'size' variable..
The complete stacktrace can give you more details

Comment: That would yield a **`ArrayStoreException`**, not a `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: Getting this only

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3

I am storing the same objects of same datatype